# The meaning of the quote: “I am he as you are he as you are me and we are all together"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, lyrics

I was in search of the usage *I'm he* or *I'm him* and came across a quote that spun my head further!

> [“I am he as you are he as you are me and we are all together - *John Lennon*](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/97751-i-am-he-as-you-are-he-as-you-are)

What does it mean?

Also, no *commas* at all? Is this quote even punctually correct?

Comment: It could be a reference to the Buddhist idea of merging with the Universe, of becoming "[at one](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_one) with everything". In this sense, all people could be seen as one being.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles_in_India. (Not really related to the question. Just something the question reminds me of. :-)

Comment: @Kreiri it doesn't work quite so well with Walrus walrus Walrus walrus walrus walrus Walrus walrus ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting a song lyric, which action is subjective.

Comment: I understand this sentence to be about grammar, specifically the "I am he" subject-complement construction, and what is going on grammatically when several of these are run together in a compound sentence (or at least, whether the line from the song is really an instance of this construction).

Comment: @BenKovitz If the question was narrowed to be about grammar, I'd be fine with re-opening it, but the question as it stands right now is "what does it mean?" not "help me understand the subject-complement construction". It's an interesting sentence, but the question needs more focus. The punctuation question I think can be answered in a comment but that's outside of my bailiwick. My comma placement has always been terrible :)

Comment: Agreed. I might VTRO if it were edited to be more like ColleenV suggests, but as-is, I'm voting to leave closed. There's no specific source of concern identified within the text.

Comment: Maulik, what didn't you like about the revision? Maybe there's a way to clarify the question to more clearly indicate what aspect of English you’re asking about. (I assume you’ve seen [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1304/6700).)

Comment: @BenKovitz It might be better if you asked the question you'd like to answer instead of making Maulik's question fit. I think it would be OK to answer your own question if it explained some construction in a way that would be useful to learners.

Comment: @ColleenV I'm only trying to reword the question so someone can give it a satisfactory answer, whatever that turns out to be. If it's really a language question, not a lit-crit song-interpretation question, it should be easy to clarify that. Exactly what aspect of the language the question is getting at is still hazy; it probably has to remain a little hazy until someone figures it out. I would have answered pretty much the same as TRomano and QOI. (I appreciate the suggestion, though.)

Comment: @BenKovitz The person who should clarify the answer is the author. If there was some ambiguity because of grammar or spelling problems, I edit to interpret it so that it reflects what I believe is the author's intent, but Maulik's English is excellent and you should give him the opportunity to clarify what he meant in his own words instead of what you assume he meant. The question isn't going to go away in the next few hours - there's time to let him sort it out.

Comment: @BenKovitz MaulikV Perhaps if it were edited to focus on what the sentence *literally* means? That would take away the subjective figurative interpretation (which is why song lyrics questions are bad, I believe) and maybe get closer to what Maulik wants than the question-about-grammar edit?

Comment: @ColleenV I was just off of this site for a day when all this happened. The edit is okay, I just did a roll-back through my mobile thinking that the question which is already closed makes no sense of editing. Anyway, I'm interested in the meaning in concern and **obviously** the *subject-complement*. ***I am he!*** -what's that? And thanks for the complement, sir! :)

Comment: Actually, editing a question is usually the first step in [getting it reopened](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: I have reverted this question back to the latest version by the OP. As @ColleenV has stated, the post is best edited by the original asker, especially when their English is good enough to do so, and **especially** when the OP started a metapost asking about the question. Given the number and quality of responses there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote is taken from a song by the Beatles (obviously) called **I am the walrus**.

[Metrolyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/i-am-the-walrus-lyrics-beatles.html) provides the lyrics, and I will just quote the first part (the rest does not make more sense than this anyway):

> I am he as you are he as you are me
>   And we are all together
>   See how they run like pigs from a gun
>   See how they fly
>   I'm crying
>
> Sitting on a cornflake
>   Waiting for the van to come
>   Corporation T-shirt, stupid bloody Tuesday
>   Man you've been a naughty boy
>   You let your face grow long
>
> I am the eggman
>   They are the eggmen
>   I am the walrus
>   Goo goo g' joob

This song was written in a time when in general Western pop music was (in part thanks to these same Beatles) under a heavy influence of Eastern philosophy and drug inspired psychedelic movement, while at the same time the press was trying to scoop all kinds of dirt on the Beatles. One of the stories of the time was that Paul McCartney was dead.

This song, apart from having indeed a psychedelic tune, had lyrics that were meant to confuse people. It was supposedly one of a few attempts to make the press realize the futility in trying to unearth all kinds of stuff about the band; attempts that failed miserably, because the fact that Paul sang the line "I'm the walrus" was, ironically, seen as an indication that in fact, he must be dead! Another "hint" that he was dead was that on the famous Abbey Road album cover, he walked barefoot. And everybody knows that when dead people walk about, they don't wear shoes.

I wouldn't try to read too much into the lyrics, as they were never supposed to convey a real message other than "some of the things we say are nonsense, why can you press mosquitoes not accept that?"

That said, obviously the first line *does* allude to the Buddhist idea of *oneness*.

Comment: I **am** the walrus, for Beatles' sake! And, yes, a lot of the song is self professed gobbly gook, in part to foil a teacher who was having her students interpret the words of Beatles songs. The first line written under LSD influence, per John.

Answer (score 2):

*A is C and B is C and A is B and we are all together*: A = B = C and they are all together because they are the same. Maybe there was some backgroud to that quote that gives it more meaning, I don't know.

Notice that he isn't consistent with the pronouns, in *I am he* and *you are he* he uses subject pronouns in the object, which would be wrong, but in *you are me* he uses an object pronoun in the object, which is right. Usage of pronouns in this kind of sentence is confusing even to many native speakers. It could also be *[artistic licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license)*.

The punctuation is correct: the words *as* link the different parts and no comma is needed before *and*.

Answer (score 2):

> I was in search of the usage *I'm he* or *I'm him*

Let's talk about Lennon's grammatical choices. I've indicated with bold where he is not consistent.

“I am he as you are he as you are **me** and we are all together - John Lennon

He doesn't say "as you are *I*" nor does he say "as I am *him* as you are *him*", although he says "as you are *me*".

Is it possible for rhyme to be more important than grammatical consistency in pop-lyrics?

Answer (score 1):

> I am he as you are he as you are me and we are all together - *John Lennon*
>
> What does it mean?

Krishna consciousness within you and without you spawned by then-legal LSD, it means and does not mean:

George is John like Yoko is Paul like Ringo is Best, and we're all breaking up the Eggman.

It refers without shadow of a doubt to tensions within the band (the eggman) that were only mollified by repeat visits to the dentist Dr Roberts for pain meds, with the phrase 'all together' a reference to the song title 'come together' Which was a plea for band unity altered by what George brought in Eric Clapton to play guitar on 'As my guitar gently weeps' but also to the song 'All together now,' the band's secretive message that it were finally disbanding. The walrus was James Joyce and the late Paul's replacement was Rocky Raccoon. Norah Jones is the daughter of the Beatles erstwhile Swami and some lady in Texas and whispered all this in to my ear after a Hare Krishna guy in the Philadelphia airport  accosted me and when he realized I was not going to donate unslipped a George Harrison album from my arm he had put there two minutes earlier.